# How to integrate payout API in Paypal with PHP application?

Tags: php, paypal

I am working on a PHP application for our client in which the users buy some products and earn some points. The points are then converted into cash and our client needs to send the cash back to his users through ther paypal email address.

I found that for sending money to users, paypal uses payout API through which we can programatically send the money to the users.

I have created a developer paypal account.

I found the article here for integrating the API: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/api-integration/#set-up-your-development-environment

But I am not sure how to use the code specified in the article here and I need PHP code for the integration.

Is there any way to get the PHP code for the integration of Payouts API with our PHP application?

Or

How to use the code specified in the article in our PHP application?

Any idea will be really helpful. I really dont know where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is information on the bottom of the page you linked to on how to set up the Payouts-PHP-SDK, if you prefer ; https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/reference/setup-sdk/#

Comment: Actually,I am trying to test the payouts API integration in localhost using xampp.

Comment: So I have downloaded the payouts PHP SDK from : https://github.com/paypal/Payouts-PHP-SDK. In this page, it has been showed the following:                                                       You can start off by trying out Samples.

Note: Update the PayPalClient.php with your sandbox client credentials or pass your client credentials as environment variable while executing the samples.                            "I have updated the paypalclient.php with the sanbox client credentials. I dont know what to do next. How to test the payment from the site in my local host using sanbox testing"?

Comment: See one of the samples for an example of sending a Payout, or read the documentation